# Distinct count with group fails though count is working fine

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm trying to convert a sql server query to **Mongo C# driver LINQ**. 
I have a table with multiple entries for each `guid` and each entry has different `code` value.
I need get a distinct count of guids for each code. I'm able to do `Count()`in LINQ but when I do `Distinct().Count()` I get the following exception:

> Specified method is not supported

Following is the T-SQL I'm trying to convert:

```
SELECT a.code, substring(convert(varchar, a.create_Date, 107), 1, 6) as create_Date,count(distinct  a.guid) as mycount
FROM table1 a (nolock) 
WHERE a.code = 0 
AND a.create_Date BETWEEN DateAdd(day,   -2  , @startDate) AND DateAdd(day, 1, @startDate)
GROUP BY a.code, substring(convert(varchar, a.create_Date, 107), 1, 6)
Order by 1
```

Following is my LINQ :

```
    var result = from tb in collection3.AsQueryable()
                 where
                 tb.code == 0
                 && tb.create_Date > rptGte
                 && tb.create_Date < rptLt
                 group tb by new
                 {
                     tb.code,
                     create_Date = tb.create_Date.DayOfYear
                 } into g
                 select new
                 {
                     code = g.Key.code,
                     create_Date = g.Key.create_Date,
                     mycount = g.Select(x => x.guid).Distinct().Count() //distinct not working here
                 };

    var resultList = rpt.ToList();
```

Please tell what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I would suggest looking into using Aggregation to accomplish this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

The key is that some Linq-to-Object constructs are not supported in Linq-to-SQL/EF. One approach is to grab the data with your `WHERE` using Linq-to-SQL/EF and then do the rest of the operations on the objects that come back in memory with Linq-to-Objects.

Without your actual data source it's impossible to test, but the following code illustrates how this can be done. Notice the first `.ToList()` call, which will fetch the results from the database, then the rest of the Linq query is done in memory on the returned objects:

```
public List<Result> GetGroupedResults(DateTime date)
{
    return table1
        .Select(x => new {x.code, x.create_Date, x.guid })
        .Where(x => 
            x.code == 0 && 
            x.create_Date > date.AddDays(-2) && 
            x.create_Date < date.AddDays(1))
        .ToList() // Fetch from database
        .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            Code = x.code, 
            CreateDateStr = x.create_Date.ToString("MMM dd")
        })
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Code)
        .Select(g => new Result
        {
            Code = g.Key.Code, 
            DateStr = g.Key.CreateDateStr, 
            Count = g.Select(x => x.guid).Distinct().Count()
        })
        .ToList();
}

public class Result
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string DateStr { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know right! This is exactly what I wanted to avoid. The pain here is that there is so much data that I wanted to avoid doing operations at the application end. But if there's no other way I guess I'll have to go this way. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you will need to bring in the un-grouped data, however if you are worried about your cloud egress costs, it will be filtered by the 3 columns and your `where` clause.

Comment: @gatsby if my answer helped, please accept and optionally up-vote it.

Comment: I'm waiting if there's another answer that can help me handle this at the database side itself. Thanks! I would deifinitely upvoted your answer though but I don't have enough reputation for that sorry!

Answer (score 0):

i believe this will give the result you want. nothing is done on the clientside as `ToList` is called at the very end to materialize the results. also, since you're already fitering by `code == 0` grouping is done on the `guid` field instead.

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class TeeBee : Entity
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public DateTime create_Date { get; set; }
        public string guid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new[] {
                new TeeBee { code = 0, create_Date = DateTime.UtcNow, guid = "xxx"},
                new TeeBee { code = 0, create_Date = DateTime.UtcNow, guid = "xxx"},
                new TeeBee { code = 0, create_Date = DateTime.UtcNow, guid = "yyy"},
                new TeeBee { code = 1, create_Date = DateTime.UtcNow, guid = "xxx"},
            }).Save();

            var result = DB.Queryable<TeeBee>() // for official driver use: collection.AsQueryable()

                           .Where(tb =>
                                  tb.code == 0 &&
                                  tb.create_Date <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1) &&
                                  tb.create_Date >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))

                           .GroupBy(tb => tb.guid,
                                   (g, tbs) => new
                                   {
                                       tbs.First().code,
                                       tbs.First().create_Date,
                                       uniqueGuids = tbs.Select(tb => tb.guid).Distinct()
                                   })

                           .Select(x => new
                           {
                               Code = x.code,
                               DateStr = x.create_Date.DayOfYear,
                               Count = x.uniqueGuids.Count()
                           })

                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm facing two issues here : 1.) you have grouped by create_Date which is a datetime field, i want to group by the day part of that field. 2.) I'm getting only 1 item in the result list when I apply your code.

Comment: @gatsby it would help if you could add some sample data from mongodb as well as the output you need. that way i could insert that test data in to mongodb and try to come up with the needed end result.